# Java HttpGet redirects to 127.0.0.1

Tags: java

I am working on a Java program with the aim of integrating data collected from a few websites into the output.  I got the API info from the sites and I can run them easily in PHP, but there is a weird issue with just one of the sites when I try to use Java.  I've got the code set up to follow redirects, but if I'm trying to access https://www.foo.com it directs me to 127.0.0.1.  It does this regardless of protocol I use or including/excluding the www.  If I take out the redirect code I get a generic "Moved Permanently" page generated.

Here is the code I'm using

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String URLString = "http://www.sickw.com/";
    URL url = new URL(URLString);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(url.toString());  //See what URL is being used
    String redirect = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
    while (redirect!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(redirect);       //Follow the redirects
        connection = new URL(redirect).openConnection();
        redirect = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
    }
    System.out.println("new " + connection.getURL().toString());    //Print the final destination

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
    int temp = inputStreamReader.read();
    while(temp!=-1)
    {
        System.out.print((char)temp);
        temp = inputStreamReader.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the site has bot detection and redirects you based on your user-agent string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            String url = "https://sickw.com";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

            System.out.println("Requested URL -> " + url);

            boolean redirect = false;

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
                    redirect = true;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Response Code -> " + status);

            if (redirect) {

                String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

                String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
                conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
                conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

                System.out.println("Redirect to URL -> " + newUrl);

            }

            StringBuilder html;
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
                String inputLine;
                html = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    html.append(inputLine);
                    html.append("\n");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("URL Content -> \n" + html.toString());
            System.out.println("Completed");

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

}
```

this works but using "https://foo.com"

Comment: You're welcome, You can mark it as correct answer if it worked for you !

Answer (score 0):

I copy, paste and run your code in my PC and get the correct page string (http://www.foo.com/)
I think your code has no problem. so please check somethings as below.

- ping test in the command line. i.e.) ping www.foo.com
- check the hosts file if it is included with redirect code.
  i.e.) 127.0.0.1      www.foo.com

Comment: I pinged the host and it works fine it seems.  One thing I did notice that whether i ping sickw.com or www.sickw.com, the result displays sickw.com.  I checked it by doing the same thing with google.com and www.google.com and that gave two different displays.  I think my input stream reader is still reading the file sent with the redirect code, but it throws a FileNotFoundException when it tries to read.  Is this just a weird website or is there something I am missing?